# parallelization in jax when the data are more than the number of devices/cores

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, parallel-processing, jax

I am trying parallel computing in jax. However, in my case, I have 100 data but only 8 cores/devices. It looks like jax.pmap() does not support this case.

I just want to know what is the easiest way when I have more data than the devices in the parallellization in jax. E.g., I want that if a core/devices finish a job and then it can calculate the next job.

```
import os
os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"] = '--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=8'
import jax


key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
N = 100
x = jax.random.normal(key, (N,))


jax.pmap(jax.numpy.square)(x)
```

Of course it reports the error:

compiling computation that requires 100 logical devices, but only 8 XLA devices are available (num_replicas=100).

Is there any way for me to parallelize the calculation when I have 100 data but only 8 devices in jax?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? There has to be a way where if there are only 8 devices but 100 data elements to process, then pmap should just "loop" through and process 8 at a time in parallel until all 100 are finished. This is essentially what Python's multiprocessing or mpi4py packages do...

Comment: @JimRaynor The jax developer told me this: https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/19452#discussioncomment-8212600. I personlly just use `joblib` now. "Jobib" works well for parallelization.